# How to label chemical structure (images) with continuing numbers in a docbook text?

Tags: xml, chemistry, docbook-5

In the chemical literature structure images are usually labelled with numbers according to the appearance in the text independently of figures. These numbers are then used to refer to the chemicals. Please point me to instructions how to do this numbering (automatically, not with predefined numbers). I have google for "chemical", "numbering", "count", "docbook", "xml" but did not get reasonable results. This numbering works flawlessly in LaTeX with appropriate packages.

Comment: I assume that docbook provide the number of  the `figure` elements authomatically. see http://tdg.docbook.org/tdg/5.0/figure.html

Comment: It is not clear what the actual, reproducible problem is. What numbering do you get now? Is "chemistry" really a relevant tag here?

Comment: "DocBook XSL: The Complete Guide" has a lot of information about numbering. See the "numbering" index entry here: http://www.sagehill.net/docbookxsl/bookindex.html.

Comment: I would like to have a counter for Chemical Structure, independent of figure numbering. We should define a figure-like Structures being counted separately from figures and refer to the xml:id of these structures to derive the Structure number. This is not covered (AFAICS) by the cited documentation.